# A seemingly simple fact about construction of maps proven categorically, i.e. by universal properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

If I have four sets $A,B,C,D$ and two maps $f_1 : A \to C$ and $f_2 : B \to D$, it is easy to find a unique map $f : A\times B \to C\times D$, namely
$$
 f(a,b) := (f_1(a), f_2(b)).
$$
But now I want to show this using the universal property of the [direct produkt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)), and that we could construct mappings between such product in all categories. The universal property reads, that for each $f_1 : Y \to C, f_2 : Y \to D$ there exists a unique map $f : Y \to C \times D$ such that
$$
 f_1 = \pi_1 \circ f \qquad f_2 = \pi_2 \circ f.
$$
So, to apply it in this case, I have to set $Y = A\times B$ in some way. Thinking in conrete sets, the maps
$$
 f_1'(a,b) = f_1(a) = (f_1\circ \pi_1)(a,b) \qquad \mbox{ and } \quad f_2'(a,b) = f_2(b) = (f_2 \circ \pi_2)(a,b)
$$
would work. But to what universal property does this "ignoring" of the first or second component corresponds... I could not reduce it to the universal property of the direct product, because there I have mappings with domain an arbitrary object, but here I have mappings which have the product as domain, so everything is reversed... Any hints? Or maybe I did something wrong and this property of SETS could not be generalized to arbitrary categories and products (of two objects)...

Comment: What do you mean "it is easy to find a unique map $f\colon A\times B\to C\times D$". There are in general more than one map between these two sets. This question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, sorry this was unclear, I meant it in the way Hagen von Eitzen answered my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A\times B$ is a product, you have projection maps $\pi_1\colon A\times B\to A$ and $\pi_2\colon A\times B\to B$ as part of the definition of product (I use the same names as for the product $C\times D$, but the context makes clear which is meant).
Now we have the maps $f_1\circ\pi_1\colon A\times B\to C$ and $f_2\circ \pi_2\colon A\times B\to D$, hence by the universal property for the product $C\times D$ a unique map $f\colon A\times B\to C\times D$ such that $\pi_1\circ f = f_1\circ \pi_1$ and $\pi_2\circ f = f_2\circ \pi_2$.

More generally, if $I$ is an index set and we have maps $f_i\colon A_i\to B_i$ for all $i\in I$, the same construction gives us a unique map $f\colon \prod_{i\in I} A_i\to \prod_{i\in I} B_i$ with the property $\pi_i\circ f=f_i\circ \pi_i$ for all $i\in I$.